# Do I need to keep the reference to a singleton object to avoid repeated initialisation?

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

Imagine that we have some singleton object:

```
class Singleton {
    static var shared = Singleton()

    private init() { ... }
}
```

Am I right that if I don't keep the reference in some place, it is initialised again and again due to the ARC every time I access it, like this:

```
Singleton.shared.doSomething()
var a = Singleton.shared.returnSomething()
```

If I am, where to keep the reference in the iOS app? In classes that use the singleton?
Or in AppDelegate, to ensure using the same instance without repeated initialisation?

Comment: `static var shared = Singleton()` <- there you keep the reference. The GC can't collect this `static` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assigning it to a `static` value you retain the shared instance and don't need to reinitialise it.  `Static` values exist at class level, not instance level, so are retained, effectively, indefinitely.